# How can i open pdf file in web browser?

Tags: java

Im want to open pdf file in web browser, but i got following error, How can i overcome this problem.. Can anyone please help me... Thanks.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Cyberbit.ttf
pdfEncoding   : Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : true
    at com.claystone.server.reports.SpeedViolationReport.service(SpeedViolationReport.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems more simply that your PDF is using the Cyberbit.ttf font, which does not seems to be present in your server. Have you first checked this font well exists on your server for producing your PDF ?

Answer (score 0):

Apperently there is a missing font. Installing the font on the client machine or embed the font with pdf file may help.